# List of releases using github api

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am trying to get releases of an app using the github API and following whatever is posted here - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository

Eg: For getting the releases list of this repo - https://github.com/fastly/epoch/releases (Am using this repo as just an example here and not actually doing anything with it), I tried `https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/releases` but this returns me a blank array.

Somewhere I read that we cannot get list of releases using the github api. Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot request **non-published** releases.

In order to get a *JSON* feed containing a list of a (owner/repo) releases using the Github Release API endpoint *"/repos/:owner/:repo/releases"* there must be published releases in that repo.

This is how a published release looks like:

[image]